# Regression - comparing two models made for two groups.

Tags: statistics, regression, regression-analysis

I used logistic regression to model a binary dependent variable (depression diagnosis) while age (continous variable) and education level (categorical variable) were independent variables. I have obtained two models for men and women separately.

I'd like to know if a change in age (or in education level) makes greater difference for men or for women. I am sure that I cannot just compare coefficents of said models.

I could run a regression model considering dummy variables of sex and look for interactions, but I am curious if there is another way of comparing two sexes using these models.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several ways to interpret your description of the logistic regression.  Let $X$ be binary random variable describing whether a particular person has depression.  Are you assuming that 
$$P(X=1 | a= A, e =E) = 1/(1+\exp(-\beta_e a + \alpha_e))$$
(Each education level has it's own simple logistic regression),
$$P(X=1 | a= A, e =E) = 1/(1+\exp(-\beta a + \alpha_e))$$
(Each education level shifts the logistic curve to the left or right), 
$$P(X=1 | a= A, e =E) = 1/(1+\exp(-\sum_{i=0}^n \beta_{ei} a^i))$$
(Each education level has it's own polynomial logistic regression), or
$$P(X=1 | a= A, e =E) = 1/(1+\exp(-\sum_{i=0}^n \beta_{i} a^i+ \alpha_e))$$
(There is one polynomial logistic regression which is shifted left or right by the education level)?

In any of the above cases, I would be tempted to measure the effect of changing education level from education level e=1 to e=2 by 
$$\mathbb E[ \mathrm{abs}(X-Y) | E=1] - \mathbb E[ \mathrm{abs}(X-Y) | E=2].$$ 
Note that $\mathrm{abs}(X-Y)=0$ iff a randomly chosen male and a randomly chosen female are either both depressed or both happy and $\mathrm{abs}(X-Y)=1$ otherwise.

The expression $\mathbb E[ \mathrm{abs}(X-Y) | E=1]$ can be interpreted as the probability that a randomly chosen man with education level 1 and a randomly chosen woman with education level 1 will not have the same depression status.

If you wanted just one number that measures the effect of changing education level, you might try
$$\sum_{i,j} P(E=i)P(E=j)(\mathbb E[ \mathrm{abs}(X-Y) | E=i] - \mathbb E[ \mathrm{abs}(X-Y) | E=j])^2.$$

Similarly, I would measure the effect of changing age from age $a_1$ to age $a_2$ by
$$\mathbb E[ \mathrm{abs}(X-Y) | A=a_1] - \mathbb E[ \mathrm{abs}(X-Y) | A=a_2]$$
and if you wanted just one number
$$\int_{a_1}\int_{a_2} f_A(a_1) f_A(a_2)( \mathbb E[ \mathrm{abs}(X-Y) | A=a_1] - \mathbb E[ Abs[X-Y] | A=a_2])^2\, da_1\, da_2.$$

There are many reasonable ways to measure the effect of changing age or educational level.